# Typeahead and ServerSide onTextChanged event not sync properly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, typeahead

I have one TextBox which have both Typeahead (autocomplete) and Server Side onTextChanged event bind to the same textbox. This two event not syncing properly. when i click some text called "a" , shows suggestions like "apple" and i select "apple" means The text "a" only captured at the server(codebehind) OnText Changed mehtod. Please give some idea to fix this.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEntityId1" name="txtEntityId1" placeholder="Search" style="width: 273px"  class="nav-search-input" runat="server" onTextChanged="text_changed" AutoPostBack="true" AutoComplete="Off"></asp:TextBox>


var EntityText = document.getElementById('<%=txtEntityId1.ClientID %>');
            try {
                $(EntityText).typeahead({
                    source: entityName,
                    updater: function (item) {
                        $(EntityText).focus();
                        return item;
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) { alert(e.Message + " , " + e.InnerException); }

protected void text_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            string EntityName = txtEntityId1.Text;
            if (EntityName != "")
            {
       }
                else
                {   //Added Check for Invalid Entity Error Message.
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "bootbox.alert('<h4 class=\"blue\">Select Valid Entity</h4>', function() {});", true);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextChanged fires when the blur event occurs, and it posts back whatever is in the value property.  Use the debugger to figure out what the input value is, and inspect that everything is wired up.  The plugin may not update the value property of the textbox; these widgets sometimes don't act how you might expect so you have to make sure the value of the input is being updated.

Can you detect whether the value is valid during the save click, or on the client instead?